# Ajax file upload without formdata

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, file, upload

when i try to upload a file, all data send to database but the input file is empty and won't upload the file how can i send file with my
actual ajax submit form ? **without dataForm** i'm new to ajax and mysql

here's my code:

```js
  

  function getUsers(){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'tpl/add.php',
  data: 'action_type=view&'+$("#userForm").serialize(),
  success:function(html){
   $('#userData').html(html);
  }
 });
}
function userAction(type,idb){
 id = (typeof idb == "undefined")?'':idb;
 var statusArr = {add:"ajouter",edit:"mises à jour",delete:"supprimer"};
 var userData = '';
 if (type == 'add') { 
  userData = $("#addForm").find('.form').serialize()+'&action_type='+type+'&idb='+idb;
  
 }else if (type == 'edit'){
  userData = $("#editForm").find('.form').serialize()+'&action_type='+type;
 }else if (type == 'view'){ 
  userData = $("#viewForm").find('.form').serialize()+'&action_type='+type;
 }else{
  userData = 'action_type='+type+'&idb='+idb;
 }

 $.ajax({
  url: 'tpl/add.php',
  cache: false,
  data: userData,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success:function(msg){
   if(msg == 'ok'){
    alert('Le model a été '+statusArr[type]+' avec succès.');
    getUsers();
    $('.form')[0].reset();
    $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   }else{
    alert('Un probleme à été detecter, veuillez reessayer.');
   }
  }
 });
}
function editUser(idb){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'JSON',
  url: 'tpl/add.php',
  data: 'action_type=data&idb='+idb,
  success:function(data){
   $('#idbEdit').val(data.idb);
   $('#modelEdit').val(data.model);
   $('#urldemoEdit').val(data.urldemo);
   $('#modelfichEdit').val(data.modelfich);
   $('#etatEdit').val(data.etat);
   $('#editForm').slideDown();
   
  }
 });
}
```

```html
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter un modele</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" id="addForm">
         <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" id="userForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Modele HTML</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="model" id="model"/>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Aperçu</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="urldemo" id="urldemo"/>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Fichier HTML </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Etat</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="etat" id="etat" class="form-control">
         <option value="0">activé</option>
         <option value="1">désactivé</option>
        </select>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" onclick="userAction('add')">Ajouter</a>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
       </div>
       </form>
   
        </div>
        
      </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object

Comment: How can i adapt it to my current code ? so the add and edit part works too